# What is the most performant way of doing a deep level update on a React Redux store?

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, redux

I am playing around with Redux and building an application driven by some sample data. In my application I have a component called "birdInfo" which has some state stored in the Redux store.

[image: Original state]

I have written a reducer to update the store with the state of the panel (if it is open or closed) but as this property is in a nested object I am having to do a number of Object.assign calls to update the state in the reducer.

I have managed to get the state to update but the bottom level object is overridden with the Object.assign call:

[image: Updated state]

Looking at the code below I could probably filter out the old panelOpen state and pass the other part of that state in the 3rd level merge, but this seems a bit clunky. I could also use `let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObj));`
 for a deep merge but this doesn't seem ideal either.

```
const toggleBirdInfo = (state, action) => {
  const newPanelState = {}  
  const newBirdInfoState = {}
  const newState = {}  

  // Update 3rd level of state object
  if (state.birdInfo[action.id].panelOpen === false) {
    Object.assign(newPanelState, state.birdInfo[action.id], {panelOpen: true})
  } else {
    Object.assign(newPanelState, state.birdInfo[action.id], {panelOpen: false})
  }

  // Update 2nd level of state object
  Object.assign(newBirdInfoState, state.birdInfo, {[action.id]: newPanelState})

  //Update 1st level of state object
  Object.assign(newState, state, {birdInfo: newBirdInfoState})

  return newState
}

const rootReducer = (state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case BIRD_INFO_TOGGLE:
      return toggleBirdInfo(state, action)
    case UPDATE_SEARCH:
      return updateSearch(state, action)
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

What is the most performant way to do this sort of deep merge?

Comment: Could you post more of your actions and reducers?

Comment: @cssko What else would you like to see? This is my only reducer at the moment (apart from the root reducer)

Answer (score 0):

I think your birdInfo reducer should look something like this:

```
const toggleBird = (state, action) => {
    return { ...state, birdInfo[action.id].panelOpen: !birdInfo[action.id].panelOpen }
}

export default function (state = {}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'TOGGLE_BIRD':
            return toggleBird(state, action);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Redux handles updating the state as a whole, you just have to focus on this little slice of the state. Using the ES6 spread syntax (the `...` in `{ ..state, }`) you just update those keys that you specify.

Please see [Using Object Spread Operator](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html) in the Redux docs, plus the Redux docs as a whole.

edit: Without the spread operator, your `toggleBird` function would look something like:

```
const toggleBird = (state, action) => {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        birdInfo[action.id].panelOpen: !birdInfo[action.id].panelOpen 
    })
}
```

Comment: I'd rather not use the Object spread syntax yet as it is not finalised. Currently using the ES2015 preset for babel which only supports array spread.

Comment: I am also only updating the part of state that I need (the panelOpen bit) but this is wiping the isVisible state.

Comment: You can use `Object.assign()` in place of the spread if you prefer. You are attempting to update much more than you need to, which is why you're losing the `isVisible` key.

Comment: Can you explain how, using Object.assign I would update the state without losing the visible key? At what stage am I updating too much? As I understand it, I am updating the bottom level into a new object then merging that object into the layer above and then merging the 2nd layer object into the layer above and returning that as the new state.

Comment: Looking into it further, I realise that "state.birdInfo[action.id].panelOpen" in the 3rd level update should just be "state.birdInfo[action.id]" which solves the problem.

Comment: You do not need to handle that merging yourself, full stop. Are you using a Root Reducer? `combineReducers` that ships with Redux is the simplest option. See the [http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/DataFlow.html](Data Flow) page on the Redux docs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153048/discussion-between-antfish-and-cssko).

Answer (score -1):

```
var data = { a: { b: { c: [ 3, 4, 5 ] } } };
const { immutable } = require('immutable')
var nested = immutable(data);

nested.update('a', () => {
                return immutable.fromJS('a')
            });
Result
nested.toJSON() = { a : a };
```